# Convert query from MS Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have limited experience with SQL but I have been asked to convert the below query from MS Access.

```
TRANSFORM SUM(weekpace_crosstab.wgt) AS SumOfwgt
    SELECT 
        Products.[Product Type], SUM(weekpace_crosstab.wgt) AS DeliveryTotal    
    FROM 
        (weekpace_crosstab 
    LEFT JOIN 
        Customer ON weekpace_crosstab.Customer = Customer.Customer)  LEFT JOIN Products ON weekpace_crosstab.Product = Products.[Product Code]
WHERE (((Customer.[Customer Group])="Sainsbury"))
GROUP BY Products.[Product Type]
PIVOT weekpace_crosstab.Date;
```

This is the result...

[image]

Through Google and other questions on this forum I have written the below statement.  However, I cannot get the delivery total to appear like in the image above.

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT P.[Product Type], wc.Date, sum (wc.wgt) AS DeliveryTotal

FROM weekpace_crosstab AS wc LEFT JOIN Customer AS C ON wc.Customer = C.Customer LEFT JOIN Products as p 

ON wc.Product = P.[Product Code]

WHERE C.[Customer Group]='Co-op'

GROUP BY  p.[Product Type], wc.Date, wc.wgt
) AS s
PIVOT 
(
SUM (DeliveryTotal)
FOR [Date] in ([2017-01-23],[2017-01-24],[2017-01-25],[2017-01-26],[2017-01-27],[2017-01-28],[2017-01-29])
)AS pvt
ORDER BY [Product Type]
```

Here is the result of this query...
[image]

Can anyone advise on how to get the delivery total column added?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Please add a tag for the form of `SQL` you are converting *to* (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL-Server`, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add in the DeliveryTotal as a second column, as the first one is being used by the pivot it will show pivoted only

Try

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT P.[Product Type], wc.Date, sum (wc.wgt) AS DeliveryTotal, w.wgt
FROM weekpace_crosstab AS wc LEFT JOIN Customer AS C ON wc.Customer = 
C.Customer LEFT JOIN Products as p 

ON wc.Product = P.[Product Code]
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT SUM(wgt)wgt, Product 
FROM weekpace_crosstab 
WHERE Date IN ('2017-01-23', '2017-01-24', '2017-01-25', '2017-01-26', '2017-01-
27', '2017-01-28', '2017-01-29')
GROUP BY product) w ON w.Product = wc.product

WHERE C.[Customer Group]='Co-op'

GROUP BY  p.[Product Type], wc.Date, w.wgt
) AS s
PIVOT 
(
SUM (DeliveryTotal)
FOR [Date] in ([2017-01-23],[2017-01-24],[2017-01-25],[2017-01-26],[2017-01-
27],[2017-01-28],[2017-01-29])
)AS pvt
ORDER BY [Product Type]
```

Comment: When i run this I do get the DeliveryTotal column however it has lost the grouping on the product type.

Comment: Just made a quick edit, added in a new join which should solve this issue.